# How does youtube start videos automatically when you open a tab, rather then after the site loaded?

Tags: javascript

If you use the `onload` event to execute a function, it executes after the site loads. Is there a similar event that fires when a tab gets opened?

Comment: Why do you need that? Modern browsers load pretty quickly.

Comment: What do you call "when a tab get opened"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See: [Window: focus event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/focus_event), [Page Visibility API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Page_Visibility_API), [tabs.onActivated](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/tabs/onActivated)

You can add an event listener to cause the video to play upon the focus of that window

```
function pause() {
  document.body.classList.add('paused');
  log.textContent = 'FOCUS LOST!';
}

function play() {
  document.body.classList.remove('paused');
  log.textContent = 'This document has focus. Click outside the document to lose focus.';
}

const log = document.getElementById('log');

window.addEventListener('blur', pause);
window.addEventListener('focus', play);
```